# How to push reference and save via POST API in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, mern

Using `express.js` framework for MERN stack app. It's my first `js` full stack app, so new to a lot of these functions. Need to `POST` a new post to a topic and also update topic. Posts with a reference to the Posts collection.

Here's `server.js`:

```
router.post('/:id/posts', (req,res) => {
  const { id } = req.params // works

  const newPost = new Post({
    post: req.body.post,
    description: req.body.description,
    topic_id: id
  })

  const topic = Topic.findById(id).then(topics => res.json(topics))

  console.log(topic.posts)
  // and I don't understand why my topic object is always undefined I need to push a reference into it I think.

  //need to save/update topic object to db
  //need to save new post
  //my other post function has newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post) and it works. but in this function it doesn't. 
});
```

this is the schema

```
const TopicSchema = new Schema({
    topic: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posts: [
        { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'post'
        }
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

If anyone could walk me through what I'm doing wrong I'd be grateful. Also pushed to [GitHub](https://github.com/wolffles/bloccit-node/blob/express/routes/api/topics.js) if more info is needed

line 31 is the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To save do this:

```
const topic = Topic.findById(id).then(topic => {
    topic.posts.push(newPost);
    topic.save(err => {
       if (err) {
         res.sendStatus(400)
       } else {
         res.sendStatus(200)
       }
    })
})
```

You can query by topic ID in the save callback if you want to send the updated topic back to client.

Comment: I believe my posts are already like that, ill edit the original post

Comment: also I used Postman to check if using 'newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));' is functional and I got the topic Json as a response and in my console got this error message.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: post validation failed: post: Path `post` is required., description: Path `description` is required.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
const topic = Topic.findById(id).then(topics => res.json(topics))
```

Here you are doing asynchronoous call  so topic will be a promise and topic.posts will be undefined (normal)

It's look like your using TypeScript or Ecmascript so you could do : (look at **async** and **await** keyword)

```
router.post('/:id/posts', async (req,res) => {

  const { id } = req.params // works

   const newPost = new Post({
     post: req.body.post,
     description: req.body.description,
     topic_id: req.body.id
   })

   try {
     const topic = await Topic.findById(id);
   }catch(err){
      // send a status 404 cause the id dont match any topic
      return;
   }
   console.log(topic.posts) //undefined but i still need to add post._id to my topic.posts 

     //attempt to save newPost object
   try {
     const post = await newPost.save();
     res.json(post);
   }catch(err){
      // You can send a internal error status cause something went wrong
   }
     // returns not post json but a topic json?
     // plus error
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code, but I'm getting this error I'm starting to think it's something else. 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: post validation failed: post: Path `post` is required., description: Path `description` is required.`

Comment: Yes here it's a typic error message from mongoose, telling you that something is missing. Do you try to update the topic after   the findById ?  Here it simply tell you that you "post" must have a property description  so perhaps  req.body.description is empty

Comment: i've edited the suggested solution to include what i've added to it. newPost const should have the required 'post', and 'description' attributes

Comment: should be good now, I deleted the .then(post => res.json(post));  from the findById, cause it was transforming the data to undefined cause  res.json is a void function and make no sens in this situation

Comment: I'm sorry I feel so dumb, It's not recognizing catch says:Unexpected token catch. I've never seen a try and catch statement before I'll have to look up some documentation. in the meantime

Comment: you are using ecma script ? typescript ? pure javascript ? I edited the answer a  '}'  was missing before the first catch.  normally it should work. You can also check this article about async/await, which is now the new way to manage asynchrone call : https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: the guide I followed originally followed on youtube for the basic mern stack app didn't say anything about ecmascript or typescript so Im sure its just pure javascript.

Comment: If you are using a node version > 8 it shoud work properly. This article could also help you : https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/